# Django Rest Framework- how to put complex SQL query in views.py

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have some problem with put sql query in Django Rest views.py.

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from ..models import Stat
from .serializers import StatSerializer

class StatListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Stat.objects.raw("SELECT parameter1, COUNT(*) FROM 
               statistic_stat GROUP BY parameter1 order by count(*) desc 
               LIMIT 10")
    serializer_class = StatSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import Stat

class StatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Stat
        fields = ('parameter1', 'parameter2')
```

When i run this code i get an error like: "get() returned more than one Stat -- it returned 122!"

The same query works in another script (with the same database) and returns the result like this:

```
[('something1', 56), ('something2', 32), ('something3', 21), ('something4', 
19), ('something5', 10), ('something6', 8), ('something7', 4), ('something8', 
3), ('something9', 2), ('something10', 1)]
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/author/

Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'statistic',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in get
  201.         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
  48.         return Response(serializer.data)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  739.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  263.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  657.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in <listcomp>
  657.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  488.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  445.             return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  104.                 instance = getattr(instance, attr)

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py" in __get__
  116.                 instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[self.field_name])

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in refresh_from_db
  696.         db_instance = db_instance_qs.get()

File "C:\Users\310041180\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  384.             (self.model._meta.object_name, num)

Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned at /api/author/
Exception Value: get() returned more than one Stat -- it returned 877!
```

Any ideas or suggestions what is wrong ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you post all of your `StatListView `? Looks like there is more code there

Comment: Yes, it's all. It works for simple query like "SELECT * FROM statistic_stat"

Comment: Without the traceback, it'll just be guesswork. Can you please provide it ?

Comment: Added. I've probably tried everything :(

Comment: Is /api/author/ really the endpoint that loads StatListView?

Comment: Yes this is endpoin that loads StatListView. For a simple query like: "SELECT * FROM statistic_stat LIMIT 10" it works.

Comment: And in statistic/api/urls.py you have r'^author/', routed to StatListView?

Comment: statisstic/api/urls.py:        urlpatterns = [url(r'^author/$', views.StatListView.as_view(),name='subject_list')]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the proper answer since I can't reproduce the error you got, but this works for me;

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework import serializers

# you're not serializing a model and since you want to display that count I guess, I'd suggest changing the serializer to this.
class StatSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    parameter1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    count = serializers.integerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('parameter1', 'count')

class StatListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Stat.objects.raw("SELECT parameter1, COUNT(*) FROM 
               statistic_stat GROUP BY parameter1 order by count(*) desc 
               LIMIT 10")
    serializer_class = StatSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        # the serializer didn't take my RawQuerySet, so made it into a list
        serializer = StatSerializer(list(queryset), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: i tried to run this code in serializers.py file and got an error "name ListAPIView is not defined"

Comment: I try to change to generics.ListAPIView, but then i get an error:                                                                                  "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `count` on serializer `StatSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Stat` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Stat' object has no attribute 'count'."

Comment: Added imports to fix the not defined. The "Got AttributeError" looks like you used the model serializer instead of the base serializer. Did you really use class StatSerializer(serializers.Serializer) or did you change it to class StatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) ? You should use serializers.Serializer for your use case.